# Todo-Tree: Invalid regular expression: /???/: Nothing to repeat - Visual Studio Code TODO-Tree Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, todo

In VS Code, I keep getting this error pop-up: `Todo-Tree: Invalid regular expression: /???/: Nothing to repeat`

Here is the TODO-Tree section of my settings:

```
    "todo-tree.regex.regex": "((//|--|#|<!--|;|/\\*|^)\\s*($TAGS)|^\\s*- \\[ \\])",

    "todo-tree.highlights.defaultHighlight": {
        "type": "text-and-comment",
        "foreground": "red",
        "fontWeight": "bold",
        "gutterIcon": true,
        "rulerLane" : "full"
    },
    "todo-tree.highlights.customHighlight": {
        "TODO": {
            "foreground" : "#f8936f",
            "rulerColour": "#f8936f",
        },
        "???": {
            "icon"       : "question",
            "foreground" : "#b777f7",
            "rulerColour": "#b777f7",
            "fontStyle"  : "italic",
        },
        "LATER": {
            "icon"       : "question",
            "foreground" : "#77f77d",
            "rulerColour": "#77f77d",
            "fontStyle"  : "italic",
        },
        "FIX": {
            "icon"       : "flame",
            "foreground" : "yellow",
            "rulerColour": "yellow",
        },
        "TMP": {
            "foreground" : "#f7ea77",
            "rulerColour": "#f7ea77",
        },
        "BUG": {
            "type"       : "text",
            "foreground" : "green",
            "rulerColour": "green",
        },
        "HACK": {
            "icon"       : "thumbsdown",
            "type"       : "text",
            "foreground" : "green",
            "rulerColour": "green"
        }
    },
    "todo-tree.general.enableFileWatcher": true,
    "todo-tree.general.revealBehaviour": "highlight todo",
    "todo-tree.general.statusBar": "current file",
    "todo-tree.tree.showCountsInTree": true,
```

I have tried messing with the regex and adding `//` to escape characters but I still have not had success.

Comment: `//` is not used to escape characters, the only char you need to escape in JSON strings is `"`, simply the regex till it works and then add bit by bit

Comment: Cannot reproduce in my VSC, but wild guess: seems that `"???"` key in customHighlight becomes (unescaped) ivalid RegExp and fails. Does the error go away if you omit that from configuration or use sth like `"\\?\\?\\?"` there instead?